# Error XDG0062 'System.Windows.Media.RectangleGeometry' is not a valid value for property 'Children'

Tags: wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have strange error in the Visual Studio at line with `<ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">`

> Error XDG0062 'System.Windows.Media.RectangleGeometry' is not a valid value for property 'Children'.
> I suspect that I don't see a control preview due to this error.

At runtime, everything looks OK. Should I worry about it, or ignore it? Maybe I should do something different?

```xml
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
            <Canvas x:Name="m_Canvas">
                <Canvas.Resources>
                    <RectangleGeometry x:Key="RectangleGeometry1">
                        <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyRectConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="m_Canvas" />
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="m_Canvas" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                    </RectangleGeometry>

                    <RectangleGeometry x:Key="RectangleGeometry2">
                        <RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyRectConverter}">
                                <Binding Path="ActualWidth" ElementName="m_Canvas" />
                                <Binding Path="ActualHeight" ElementName="m_Canvas" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </RectangleGeometry.Rect>
                    </RectangleGeometry>
                </Canvas.Resources>

                <Path Fill="#35A500"
                      Opacity="0.15">
                    <Path.Data>
                        <GeometryGroup FillRule="EvenOdd">
                            <StaticResource ResourceKey="RectangleGeometry1" />
                            <StaticResource ResourceKey="RectangleGeometry2" />
                        </GeometryGroup>
                    </Path.Data>
                </Path>
            </Canvas>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: "*Should I worry about it, or ignore it?*" Ignore it of course. It's just the XAML Designer complaining about valid XAML.

Comment: You can try to Clean and Rebuild your solution.